# Как сделать список в два столбца?

Tags: php, html, css

У меня пользователи выводится с помощью цикла в один столбец, а как сделать в два столбца?

```
 <div class="all_users2">

  <br/>

  <?
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT login,id,avatar   FROM users ORDER BY login",$db); //    извлекаем логин и идентификатор пользователей 
        $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        do
        {
        //выводим их в цикле 
        printf(" <a    href='page.php?id=%s'><img src='%s' width='90' height='90'  /> %s</a><br>",$myrow['id'],$myrow['avatar'],$myrow['login']);
        }
        while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
   ?>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В CSS3 есть спецификация [CSS Multi-column Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/) (Candidate Recommendation с 2011 года), поддерживается (с вендорными префиксами) [всеми браузерами кроме IE<10 и Opera<11.1](http://caniuse.com/multicolumn), позволяет разбивать текст на колонки, на манер того как это часто делают в печатных изданиях.

Простейшая демонстрация http://jsfiddle.net/HTM6E/2/

Описания http://habrahabr.ru/post/153955/ http://habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/143158/

Но если нужна поддержка альтернативных и устаревших браузеров то приходится делать такие вещи на стороне сервера, как это уже описали выше.

Comment: Самый простой и легкий способ =) Только вот вторая ссылка в "Описания" не рабочая, у меня не открывает.

Comment: Просто загугли "site:habrahabr.ru css column", там как минимум три поста отдельно про Multi-column Layout Module и много всяко-другого интересного. Хотя вроде со ссылкой всё в порядке.

Answer (score 0):

Массив сначала делишь, а потом как обычно.

[array_chunk](http://www.php.su/functions/?array-chunk)

> Функция array_chunk() разбивает массив на несколько массивов размером размер значений. Последний массив из полученных может содержать меньшее количество значений, чем указано. В качестве результата функция возвращает многомерный массив с индексами, начинающимися с нуля и элементами, которыми являются массивы, полученные в результате разбивки.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT `login`,`id`,`avatar` FROM `users` ORDER BY `login`",$db);
  $i=0;
  while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
       {

         $row[$i]['id'] = $myrow['id'];
         $row[$i]['avatar'] = $myrow['avatar'];
         $row[$i]['login'] = $myrow['login'];
         $i++;
       }

  $count = ceil(count($row)/2);

  $chunk = array_chunk($row,$count);

  for($i=0;$i < count($chunk[0]);$i++)
     {
       printf(" <a href='page.php?id=%s'><img src='%s' width='90' height='90'  /> %s</a><br>",$myrow[0][$i]['id'],$myrow[0][$i]['avatar'],$myrow[0][$i]['login']);
     }
  echo "<p> Как-нить разделяем </p>";

    for($i=0;$i < count($chunk[1]);$i++)
     {
       printf(" <a href='page.php?id=%s'><img src='%s' width='90' height='90'  /> %s</a><br>",$myrow[1][$i]['id'],$myrow[1][$i]['avatar'],$myrow[1][$i]['login']);
     }
```

Код нету возможности проверить. Где то так.

Comment: Попробовал, выводит только сообщение "Как-нить разделяем". Ошибок таких серьезных не заметил.

Comment: @lifting включено отображение ошибок?
    print_r($row);

Что вам выдаст?

Comment: И включать пробовал, нет, не показывает ошибки. Просто сейчас выводит вот так [скриншот][1]
[1]: http://s019.radikal.ru/i605/1406/a3/c871be0702e4.png